# How to Disable/Enable WiFi automatic switching in Android programmatically from our android application?

Tags: android

I was connected to device hotspot and with in few seconds it is switching back to Home wifi network, where my task was getting hampered in middle.
I just want to stay in the same network until I complete my task even its network(or Signal) strength is low compared to Home wifi network.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can (or would want to) do this.  What would happen to any other app which was depending, e.g., on WiFi, and now got switched off?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but there are situations where you would want to have that. For eg. during google-chromecast setup,the google-home locks the device to chromecast's hotspot access point. But I too am looking for how it does.